# Como convertir una oracion a piglatin

Tags: python

Me pregunto si me pueden ayudar?

tengo que hacer PIGLATIN a una palabra.  piglatin es tomar la primera letra de la palabra y pasarla al final sumado a la palabra ay.
yo creo que logre hacerlo, pero mi pregunta es como puedo hacerlo en una oracion es decir cada palabra por ejemplo

`hola diana` quedaria `olahay ianaday`

el codigo que tengo para una palabra es este :

debo usar un codigo recursivo? que ademas aun no entiendo ni domino bien.

```
pygequal= input("Enter a word to be convert to piglatin ")

if pygequal>'0' and pygequal.isalpha():
#(len(pygequal)>0) Asi lo hizp el profesor porque le
#daba error cuando yo lo vi pense que eran las comlillas y lo hice asi y fuinciona
    print(pygequal)
    
    primeraletra = pygequal[0]
    print(primeraletra)
    
    newword= pygequal[1: len(pygequal)]
    print(newword)
    resultadopiglatin = newword + primeraletra + 'ay'
    print(resultadopiglatin)
    print(type(newword))
    
else:
    print(" wrong Entry must be alpha ")
```

Comment: Te aconsejo cambiar: `  newword= pygequal[1: len(pygequal)]` por `  newword= pygequal[1: ];` recuerda que cuando se deja una parte vacía en `[0:]` significa todo lo que sigue a 0.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo, el problema que tienes es que no sabes cómo separar la frase en palabras. Lo más sencillo es usar el método `.split()`:

```py
words = pygequal.split()

print(words)
```

El método `.split()` separa las palabras separadas que están separadas por espacios. Podría haber un problema si se usan signos de puntuación para separación, pero parace que descartas esos casos al chequear la frase con `.isalpha()`.

De todos modos, `pygequal` es una cadena de caracteres y *espacios*. Hay que separar las palabras primero antes de hacer la comprobación con `.isalpha()` (lo veremos más adelante).

Una ver convertidas las palabras a *pyglatin* se pueden volver a recombinar con el método `.join()`.

Lo primero es definir la función que hará la conversión:

```py
def pyglatin_encode(w: str) -> str:
    return f"{w[1:]}{w[0]}ay" if len(w) > 0 else ""
```

Combinando con tu código:

```py
pygequal= input("Enter a word to be convert to piglatin ")

if len(pygequal) > 0:
    words = pygequal.split()
    result = " ".join(pyglatin_encode(w) for w in words if w.isalpha())
    print(result)
else:
    print(" wrong Entry must be alpha ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que necesitas es usar el método `split()` que te devuelve una lista con todas las palabras separadas.

```py
frase = "hola diana"

palabras = frase.split() #separamos las palabras 
piglatin = [f"{p[1:]}{p[0]}ay" for p in palabras] #creamos la palabra piglatin
piglatin = " ".join(piglatin) #unimos todo
print(piglatin)
```

Yo he simplificado todo tu codigo usando una comprensión de lista, donde comemos todas las letras exceptuando la primera (`p[1:]`) , le agregamos la primera letra junto con `ay` (`p[0] ay`).

Y el método join nos sirve para volver a juntar todos los elementos de la lista.

Si no entiendes muy bien la compresión de lista puedes hacer esto:

```py
frase = "hola diana"

palabras =frase.split()
piglatin = []

for p in palabras:
    primera = p[0]
    resto = p[1:]
    palabra = f"{resto}{primera}ay"
    piglatin.append(palabra)

piglatin = " ".join(piglatin)
print(piglatin)
```